# nil.to_json cannot be parsed back to nil?

Tags: ruby

This snippet throws an exception:

```
x = nil
jsoned = x.to_json
puts 'x.to_json=' + jsoned.inspect
puts 'back=' + JSON.parse(jsoned).inspect

C:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/json/common.rb:146:in `parse': 706: unexpected token at 'null'      (JSON::ParserError)
x.to_json="null"
from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/json/common.rb:146:in `parse'
from C:/dev/prototyping/appoxy_app_engine/test/temp.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
from -e:1:in `load'
from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Is that expected behavior? I would think this should work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is not specifically with `nil`. It's that `to_json` on a simple thing like `nil` or a single string doesn't produce a full JSON representation.

e.g. something like `JSON.parse("hello".to_json)` would yield similar results

If we have a `Hash` with `nil` for one of its values it will encode and decode correctly:

```
>> h = {"name"=>"Mike", "info"=>nil}
=> {"name"=>"Mike", "info"=>nil}
>> h.to_json
=> "{\"name\":\"Mike\",\"info\":null}"
>> JSON.parse(h.to_json)
=> {"name"=>"Mike", "info"=>nil}
```

Comment: You haven't, per se, answered the question.  Is to_json incorrectly producing "invalid" JSON, or is JSON.parse failing to parse "valid" JSON?  Either way, this should not be expected behavior within ruby.  I'd expect serialize/deserialize to be consistent with one another, regardless of the underlying medium.

Comment: Neither: to_json is correctly producing invalid JSON.  When you call to_json on a single value like nil, you're in effect saying "Show me how this value would be represented as a JSON value."  That's a sensible thing to do in some cases, but a non-object non-array value is still not a valid JSON text.

Answer (score 16):

The JSON parser has a "quirks mode" in which it will parse single JSON values.

```
>> nil.to_json
=> "null"
>> JSON.parse("null", {:quirks_mode => true})
=> nil
```

It also works for other single values:

```
>> JSON.parse("12", {:quirks_mode => true})
=> 12
>> JSON.parse("true", {:quirks_mode => true})
=> true
>> JSON.parse(" \"string\" ", {:quirks_mode => true})
=> "string"
```

Comment: Why ruby JSON lib doesn't make quirks_mode as its default mode? Does quirks_mode have any special parse result? Does quirks_mode means default mode + single JSON value parser?

Comment: The top level of a JSON text must be either an object `{}` or an array `[]`.  The single values included above are neither objects nor array, and therefore are not JSON texts, strictly construed.  Quirks mode allows parsing single values like those above -- it's not the default because it handles a non-standard case.

Answer (score 1):

JSON doesn't like single objects, it's really for serializing collections of objects.  If you try something like this, you can see that it really does generate valid JSON for nil objects and can de-serialize them.

```
n = JSON.parse( JSON.generate([nil]) )  # => [nil]
```

Comment: In Ruby, Array and Nil are both objects.