# Decode JSON in rails simple string raises error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I'm trying to roundtrip encode/decode plain strings in json, but I'm getting an error.

In rails 2.3. w/ ruby 1.8.6, it used to work.

```
>> puts ActiveSupport::JSON.decode("abc".to_json)
abc
=> nil
```

In rails 3.1beta1 w/ ruby 1.9.2, it raises an error.

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :001 > puts ActiveSupport::JSON.decode("abc".to_json)
MultiJson::DecodeError: 706: unexpected token at '"abc"'
    from /home/stevenh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/json/common.rb:147:in `parse'
    from /home/stevenh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/json/common.rb:147:in `parse'
    from /home/stevenh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/multi_json-1.0.1/lib/multi_json/engines/json_gem.rb:13:in `decode'
    [...]
```

This is pretty much the same question discussed at [nil.to_json cannot be parsed back to nil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552328/nil-to-json-cannot-be-parsed-back-to-nil)

But nil used to work in 2.3/1.8.7 as well.

```
puts ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(nil.to_json)
nil
```

Is this the new normal?

Comment: Since the string "abc" is not valid JSON a DecodeError seems appropriate to me.

Comment: I have to agree with @polarblau, especially since: 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :012 > ActiveSupport::JSON.decode({:abc => "test"}.to_json)
 => {"abc"=>"test"}

Comment: @polarblau, @Yardboy: I disagree: `ActiveSupport::JSON.decode("abc".to_json)` decodes `"\"abc\""` and not "abc". The problem is that the decoder does not work correctly for simple strings.

Comment: @mosch Perhaps. Digging a little deeper, the issue appears to have come in with 3.1.0.rc1, when the ActiveSupport JSON backend was swapped out for MultiJson (pull request: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/289). I submitted an issue to the multi_json github project asking about this (https://github.com/intridea/multi_json/issues/17) - maybe they'll have some insight.

Comment: @Yardboy: Thanks for the work. This is good to know: It doesn't work and it shouldn't ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This change occurred with the [switch from ActiveSupport's JSON backend to MultiJson](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/289) that was included in Rails 3.1.0.rc1. Per the [MultiJson project team](https://github.com/intridea/multi_json/issues/17), the current behavior is correct and the previous implementation was faulty due to [RFC4627](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt?number=4627)'s specification of the JSON grammar:

```
2.  JSON Grammar

   A JSON text is a sequence of tokens.  The set of tokens includes six
   structural characters, strings, numbers, and three literal names.

   A JSON text is a serialized object or array.

      JSON-text = object / array
```

As neither `"abc"` nor `"/"abc/""` are serialized objects or arrays, an error when attempting to decode them is appropriate.

The diagrams from the [JSON website](http://www.json.org/) reinforce this specification.

That being said, this would seem to imply a bug in the to_json implementation that results in:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :001 > "abc".to_json
 => "\"abc\""
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, what is happening in Rails3 is the new normal.  The changes you illustrate seem like a reflection of a maturing framework.

Methods named "encode" & "decode" should be expected to be perfectly compliant with [the JSON spec](http://www.json.org/), and inverses of one another.

String#to_json, on the other hand is a behavior-ish type of method that functions as a convenience for building more complex JSON objects presumably used internally (within ActiveSupport) when Array#to_json or Hash#to_json encounter a String value as one of their consituent elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to restore that behavior follow [these steps](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1499#issuecomment-2258410), i.e.

```
# in your Gemfile
gem 'yajl-ruby'

# in your application.rb
require 'yajl/json_gem'
```

After those steps:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.8)
[1] pry(main)> puts ActiveSupport::JSON.decode("abc".to_json)
abc
=> nil
[2] pry(main)> puts ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(nil.to_json)

=> nil
```