# How to read a Hash with null as a value in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Here is what I have: (dynamically generated Hash)

```
actual = { "posts": [ { "id": 3, "title": "Post 3" } ], "profile": { "name": "" }, "nulldata": { "res": null } }
```

**Output**

```
undefined local variable or method `null' for main:Object
```

What I need:

- To somehow read the above hash (first option)
- or to replace the value, `null` which will be appearing in multi key-pair locations (second option)

sample api response with null value

```
{
   "data":{
      "type":"user",
      "id":"33896",
      "attributes":{
         "name":"James Guy",
         "br":"Test Account",
         "phone":"97...0716",
         "secondary_phone":"",
         "is_active":true,
         "preferredLanguage":"en",
         "is_cli":true,
         "did_number":"971...007",
         "roles":"Admin, Agent",
         "last_connection":"17/10/2019 10:23",
         "position":""
      },
      "links":{
         "photo":"https://.../desktop",
         "edit":"https://.../users/33896/edit/",
         "toggle_active":"https://.../users/33896/toggle_active",
         "link_a":null,
         "a_mobile":null,
         "a_landLine":null,
         "una":null
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: How do you _dynamically generat that hash_?

Comment: If `null` is undefined, then clearly you do _not_ have that hash. You might have a block of JSON looking like that. Is that it?

Comment: I get it from the api response

Comment: But it can't be just `null`, because it would be an undefined local variable, or does it?. What's the code previous to that?

Comment: @SebastianPalma I updated one of my api response data in the question

Comment: There are multi-fields with `null `as a value; when I assign this data to a variable, I get an exception

Comment: @SebastianPalma it considers the null as a variable; you can try here
https://repl.it/repls/CrowdedRichSoftwareengineer

Comment: What are you using to parse the response?

Comment: It fails before parsing; if you check the above repl link, it explains my issue

Comment: @SebastianPalma if I do JSON.parse(...), the null value is converted into nil; but, I have to read the Hash even before parsing it. In this case, it throws exception

Comment: @PrashanthSams not all Json hashes are valid Ruby hashes. This one is not valid Ruby, because of `null`. So you _need_ to Json parse it.

Comment: @maxpleaner I am actually passing the non-parsed Json as a parameter; so, it fails in the call itself. like custom_json(non_json_parsed_hash, param2)

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552328/nil-to-json-cannot-be-parsed-back-to-nil

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't try to copy and paste this JSON directly in Ruby if you do something like that. JSON is a string, so wrap it using `%{}` so as to avoid double quotes escaping:

```
[4] pry(main)> s = %{ # press enter
[4] pry(main)* {
[4] pry(main)*    "data":{
[4] pry(main)*       "type":"user",
... # all the contents goes here
... # press enter
[4] pry(main)* } # this is the closing bracket
```

Then

```
require 'json' # if needed
[11] pry(main)> JSON.parse s
=> {"data"=>
  {"type"=>"user",
   "id"=>"33896",
   "attributes"=>
    {"name"=>"James Guy",
     "br"=>"Test Account",
     "phone"=>"97...0716",
     "secondary_phone"=>"",
     "is_active"=>true,
     "preferredLanguage"=>"en",
     "is_cli"=>true,
     "did_number"=>"971...007",
     "roles"=>"Admin, Agent",
     "last_connection"=>"17/10/2019 10:23",
     "position"=>""},
   "links"=>
    {"photo"=>"https://.../desktop",
     "edit"=>"https://.../users/33896/edit/",
     "toggle_active"=>"https://.../users/33896/toggle_active",
     "link_a"=>nil,
     "a_mobile"=>nil,
     "a_landLine"=>nil,
     "una"=>nil}}}
```

There is no such keyword as `null` in Ruby. Every `null` becomes `nil`